# HTML img stitching , make image borderless,margin-less

Tags: html, css, image

I want to stitch a bunch of image using html , but the problem is they have margin , i use web inspector to look for which properties that affect this, but an hour or less still cant figure it out.

i have tried using negative margin-left, negative position using psuedo selector , although it 
work perfectly , but that is not the way right?

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2321732/stitch_images/index.html

So now i want the cleanest way to stitch make the image does not have any margin.

Comment: is using of css is not an option?

Comment: yes use css, i want a very clean way of making it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following:

```
body {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

It's because of the new lines in your sourcecode, which the browser renders as spaces.

The above prevents the spaces from being rendered, but you can also just remove the line breaks from your sourcecode (hence the tags are all on one line).

Comment: yes it work, i have to code it this way to make a clean html , because it contain thousand of small images have to stitch together

Answer (score 2):

Write the img-tags in one line

```
    <img src="images/0_0.jpg" alt=""><img src="images/1_0.jpg" alt=""><img src="images/2_0.jpg" alt="">
    <br>

    <img src="images/0_1.jpg" alt=""><img src="images/1_1.jpg" alt=""><img src="images/2_1.jpg" alt="">
    <br>

    <img src="images/0_2.jpg" alt=""><img src="images/1_2.jpg" alt=""><img src="images/2_2.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: this method will cause the html code very long , because the i will be stitching 43x33 small images to form a large images, if using this way my html will be very wide

Comment: Yes, I know. Abody97's answer is much better. I have not come up with the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Set your images to `display: block; float: left` and your br `float: left; clear: right`

Answer (score 2):

Abody97's solution may cause problem if you are using em's as sizing unit. And writing everything in one line makes it harder to read.
You could instead make the images `float: left` and set `overflow: hidden` to the parent element.
However, if for whatever reason you can't float the elements you could use comments, like so:

```
<div>
    <img src="1.jpg" alt=""><!--
 --><img src="2.jpg" alt=""><!--
 --><img src="3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```